# Can't find Bluetooth LE device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am doing project to detect the BLE device surround you. But however the device can't find any BLE device near by. Device supports BLE, but my coding can't detect the BLE device. Please help me if any mistake or anything missing.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BluetoothLeScanner leScanner;
ArrayList<ScanFilter> scanFilters;
ScanSettings settings;
ProgressDialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button scanStartbtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.startscanbtn);
    final BluetoothAdapter adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    settings=new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
    scanFilters=new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
    scanStartbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            leScanner=adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            leScanner.startScan(scanFilters,settings,mScanCallback);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Scanning started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}



ScanCallback mScanCallback=new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hey I found BLE device+onScanResult" + result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
        dialog.dismiss();
        for(ScanResult result:results) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hey I found BLE device" + result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);

        if(errorCode==1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Scan is already started" + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(errorCode==3)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Scan is interrupted due to internal error" + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unexpected error" + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have used BluetoothLeScanner object leScanner.startScan(). which is come on api 21 and its not backward compitable.

Comment: Why do you need a BluetoothLeScanner ?

Comment: To scan the nearest BLE device. whether any ble device available or not. if available then its callback method onBatchScanResults() will give you the all bunch of the ble devices in list structure.

Comment: I think if you don't understand  List<ScanFilter>  and ScanSettings  , you can try leScanner.startScan( final ScanCallback callback).

Comment: I don't see any (obvious) error in your code. Which android version does your device have? Remember from android 6 on, you have to include location permission and activate the location in the settings.

Comment: Yes, on Android 6.0 marshmellow device is not supported. After adding the location permission COARSE_LOCATION AND FINE_Location. and also after activating gps couldn't help search BLE device.

Comment: take a look at Google sample project: https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Answer (score 0):

I think code below is enough :

```
final BluetoothAdapter adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        adapter.startLeScan(new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

            }
        })
```